# MVC Ajax.BeginForm helper not reaching action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

AjaxOptions defintion looks like this:

```
    @using VaultSearch.Models
    @model UserInfo
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Vault Search Engine";
        AjaxOptions ajaxOptionsDocGroupsForm = new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "divSearchFieldRows",
            Url = Url.Action("GetDocGroupSearchFields"),
            LoadingElementId = "loadingSearchFields",
            LoadingElementDuration = 5000,
        };
     }
```

The Ajax.BeginFrom helper that uses it is able to show the loading element.
But the URL.Action, "GetDocGroupSearchFields", which should return a PartialVeiwResult does not seem to get called.

That from looks like this:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxOptionsDocGroupsForm))
{
    @Html.Action("GetDocumentGroups", new { userId = Model.Id })

    <button type="submit">Get Search Fields >></button>
}
```

And the html rendered is this:

```
<div class="docGroupsWrapper">
    <form action="/" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loadingSearchFields" data-ajax-loading-duration="5000" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#divSearchFieldRows" data-ajax-url="/Home/GetDocGroupSearchFields" id="form0" method="post">
    <b>Document Groups:</b>

    <select id="DocGroupItems" name="DocGroupItems">
        <option value="">--Select One--</option>
        <option value="3">AuthLetters</option>
        <option value="4">SummaryVouchers</option>
        <option value="5">ExplanationOfBenefits</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Get Search Fields >></button>
    </form>

    <div id="divSearchFields" class="searchFieldsWrapper">

    <div id="loadingSearchFields" class="load" style="display:none">
        <p>loading Document Search Fields...</p>
    </div> 

    <div id="divSearchFieldRows">
        <span class="instructions">
             Choose a Document Group from above to see columns to search with. >>
         </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it is just not hitting the Action in the Home Controller: GetDocGroupSearchFields, which just looks like this for now:

```
public PartialViewResult GetDocGroupSearchFields(int docGroupId)
    {
        List<DocumentGroupField> searchFields = new List<DocumentGroupField>();

        return PartialView();
    }
```

And the Partial View returned is just this:

```
@using VaultSearch.Models
@model List<DocumentGroupField>

<b>Search Fields!!!</b>
```

So, the only thing I really have working is the loading div.

I have all of these concepts working from Adam Freeman's APRESS book: Pro ASP.Net MVC 4, Chapter 21 buildup.

I'm doing pretty much the same thing here. Can't figure out why it is not working.
Adam does not specify any post verbs or ChildAction attributes in his example and it is all working.

Comment: I just noticed the Ajax.BeginFrom helper puts a method=post in the rendered form.

So, i just added a [HttpPost] attribute to the action that returns the PartialViewResult.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action seem to expect a `docGroupId` integer parameter. In your view you never supply a value to it. So when you look at the AJAX request being sent to the server in FireBug or Chrome Developer Toolbar you will see a response from the server:

> A required parameter docGroupId has not been supplied a value.

So make sure you provide a value for this parameter when generating your url or make it a nullable integer if you do not intend to pass it a value:

```
Url = Url.Action("GetDocGroupSearchFields", new { docGroupId = "123" })
```

Alternatively you could include it as a hidden field inside the form:

```
@Html.Hidden("docGroupId", "123")
```

Comment: Thanks - I removed the docId param for now and I got my Partial View back via the AJAX helper.